# Display polyline on Google Maps

Tags: java, google-maps

I'm using Java client for Google Maps from https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java to get directions. The client returns all data I need, including the polyline for the route.
Is it possible to use this polyline and create an URL that would draw the route on Google Maps, something like: https://www.google.com/maps/polyline=sdfwf43r34534

Answer (score 0):

with polyline, i use this kind of address to get a static map (jpg) with polyline on it:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&client=MY_CLIENT_ID&size=500x500&format=jpg&markers=label:FROM|city_from&markers=label:TO|city_to

then i append:

&path=enc:the_polyline

where "the_polyline" is the polyline value i get from directions

Comment: I've tired this to, but it is a static map, so you cannot zoom in, zoom out, move the map around, ... I'd much rather have polyline drawn on regular interactive map.